# Multiple Tables with Common Column

Tags: php, mysql

I have one database named "production_db" and it has 6 tables inside. All tables have a **Common Column** named as "dueDate". I made a php page where the user can search all of the tables based on the date input and will show the result in a single page. The code below shows only the result from a single table.

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px">
    <legend><b>Search Delivery Date Schedule</b></legend>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Search orders that are set to deliver on</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm datepick" name="dueDate" style="text-align:center" value="<?php echo !empty($dueDate)?$dueDate:'';?>">
        </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn-success form-control btn-sm">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form><br>

    <?php
        include 'pages/database.php';

        $dueDate = isset($_POST['dueDate']) ? $_POST['dueDate'] : '';

        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM aafes WHERE dueDate ='$dueDate'";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($dueDate));
        $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (($data)==0) { 
            echo 'Search Results';

        } else {    
            echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">'; 
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th style="text-align:center">Order No</th>';
                echo '<th style="text-align:center">Order Date</th>';
                echo '<th style="text-align:center">Delivery Date</th>';
                echo '<th style="text-align:center">Facility Name</th>';
                echo '<th style="text-align:center">Total Quantity</th>';
            echo '</tr>'; 
            foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
            echo '<tr>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="10%">'. $row['orderNo'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="10%">'. $row['orderDate'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="10%">'. $row['dueDate'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="10%">'. $row['facilityName'] . '</td>';
                 echo '<td style="text-align:center" width="6%">'. $row['totalQty'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            }
            }               
        Database::disconnect();

    ?>
</div>
```

[image: index page-this is where the result will show]

[image: table1]

So how do I combine these 6 tables into one table based on their **"dueDate"**?

Comment: What do you mean by combine ? Do you need a query to join all these tables  (I mean fetch data from all the tables ) ?

Comment: And by the way , your code is not secure. It looks like sql injection is possible as you set param in your query just through =. This line : "SELECT * FROM aafes WHERE dueDate ='$dueDate'";

Comment: @john yes! I want to combine them based on their scheduled due date and how do I secure this code?

Comment: Here's a nice guide on JOINs http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins @Richelle and to make it secure, he's the PDO prepared statements manual http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: thanks @Fred-ii- i'll check this references